# i want to prevent overlap .on(click) in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prevent overlap this one `$("#print").on('click', function(ev) {`.
so i add  `.off()` to `$("print").on('click', function(ev){`
but it doesn't work.
if i click id="print" repeatedly, it makes a lot of button "복사하기"
please help me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#print").off().on('click', function(ev) {
        $('#main').prepend('<center><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="print2">복사하기</button></center>')
        $('.post').prepend('<input type="checkbox" />');
        $("#print2").on('click', function() {
            var images = '';
            $('li').each(function() {
                var thisCheckFlag = $(this).children('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked');
                if (thisCheckFlag) {
                    images += '<img src ="' + $(this).find('img').attr('src') + '">';
                }
            });
            if (images) {
                var myWindow = window.open('', 'printWindow', 'width=800,height=800');
                myWindow.document.write(
                    '<html><head><title>Print</title></head><body>' + images + '</body></html>'
                );
                myWindow.focus();
                myWindow.print();
            } else alert('먼저 선택하세요.');
        });
        ev.preventDefault();
    });


});
```

Comment: Use `one()` to bind the event `$('#print').one('click', function(ev) {`.

Comment: @Tushar Thanks for your advice. but if i click #print twice, the button id="print2" is disappear. i want it to be not change.

Comment: Why would "off" make it work once? You are adding the onclick, you would need to remove it after you click.